# Python - value in list of dictionaries

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to search for a Python dictionary value in a list of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580270/whats-the-best-way-to-search-for-a-python-dictionary-value-in-a-list-of-dictiona)

I have a list of dictionaries in the form

```
my_dict_list = []
my_dict_list.append({'text':'first value', 'value':'number 1'})
my_dict_list.append({'text':'second value', 'value':'number 2'})
my_dict_list.append({'text':'third value', 'value':'number 3'})
```

I also have another list in the form:

```
results = ['number 1', 'number 4']
```

how can I loop through the list of `results` checking if the value is in `dict`, e.g.

```
for r in results:
    if r in my_dict_list:
        print "ok"
```

Comment: Please fix your question. 1) That's not a dictionary, 2) What is `value`?

Comment: Please don't name a list `dict` or use built-ins as variable names. It just makes a mess of things. . .

Comment: this was just an example that i put together not the original code but I'll fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks. Even though it's just an example, I'd like to be able to just cut and paste it into my working environment without having to deal with issues that arise because `dict` is now an empty list instead of the python built-in. It slows my ability to help you, which makes me not want to (and I do)

Comment: @JoshAdel: no problem. It was just me being lazy and not thinking about the code I was giving as an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for r in result:
  for d in dict:
    if d['value'] == r:
       print "ok"
```

Comment: Much shorter if you don't need to print "ok" multiple times if the value exist multiple times: `if any(d['value'] == r for d in dicts): ...`

Answer (score 4):

`map(lambda string: any(map(lambda item: item['value'] == string, dict)), results)` returns a list of `[True, False]` for the given `results`. Although using `for` is more appropriate here, because you can break the nested loop when a value is found. `any` will go through all the items in `dict`.

Also, don't call a list `dict` and don't use built-in type/function names as variables.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your case, your dict variable is not a dictionnary, it's a list of 3 dictionnaries, each dictionnary containing 2 keys (text and value). Note that I supposed that either value is a variable or zthat you forgot quotes around it (I added them here)

```
[{'text': 'second value', 'value': 'number 2'}, {'text': 'third value', 'value': 'number 3'}, {'text': 'first value', 'value': 'number 1'}]
```

If that's what you expected, then you can use something like:

```
mySetOfValues=set([x['value'] for x in my_dict_list])
for r in results:
  if r in mySetOfValues:
    print 'ok'
```

However, if I understand correctly, maybe you wanted to create a dictionnary associating first value to number 1 ?