# Search for value in a key from list of dictionaries and return a different key value

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary, key

Continued from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580270/whats-the-best-way-to-search-for-a-python-dictionary-value-in-a-list-of-dictiona). 
I have the following data structure:

```
data = [
  {'site': 'Stackoverflow', 'id': 1},
  {'site': 'Superuser', 'id': 2}, 
  {'site': 'Serverfault', 'id': 3}
]
```

I want to search all 'site' keys for a specific value, and return that dictionary's 'id' value.  For example, searching 'Superuser' should return 2:

```
>>> print find_id('Superuser')
2
```

When I tried using the referenced question's solution, I received an error:

```
>>> if any(d['site'] == 'Superuser' for d in data): print d['Superuser']
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
>>> if any(d['site'] == 'Superuser' for d in data): print data['Superuser']
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What's the most pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: `def find_id(data, name): return next((d['id'] for d in data if d['site'] == name), None)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tricks here. Just do:

```
def find_id(data, name):
    for d in data:
        if d['site'] == name:
            return d['id']
```